# How to reverse sandbox refresh without activation

Tags: sandbox

I have clicked refreshed sandbox but I do not want to activate it now. Is there any way to get my sandbox back. I mean can I remove this "activate" option.
I am system admin.
Please help ASAP. Please.

Comment: Did you find a solution for your problem?

Answer (score 10):

Just create a ticket with support and ask them to remove that refresh, they can do that.